# facebook graph api to get follower count of different account

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I need to get different user follower counts through facebook graph api. I get the user id through user name but how i get the follower count of that user.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're facing at least two problems here:

1) The `username` field has been deprecated with Graph API v2.0
2) The `/{user_id}/subscribers` edge has been deprecated with Graph API v2.0

I guess you'll not be able to do what you want to achieve unfortunately.

See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0_graph_api